# How to extract edge list of communities in igraph?

Tags: r, social-networking

I'm using igraph for community detection and of course it plots communities in the graph. 
What I would like to do is to write each computies as edge list in a text file. Unfortunately I couldn't find any function in igraph that does this.
Would someone can help me with this?

```
karate <- make_graph("Zachary")
wc <- cluster_walktrap(karate)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the induced subgraph,  turn that into an edgelist and write it out. I am assuming that you wish to preserve the original numbering of the vertices, so I added a line to do that.

```
## Your setup
library(igraph)
karate <- make_graph("Zachary")
wc <- cluster_walktrap(karate)

###########  Answer #########
for(i in seq_along(wc)) { 
    Community = induced_subgraph(karate, wc[[i]])
    V(Community)$name <- wc[[i]]        ## To preserve original node numbers
    EL = as_edgelist(Community)
    FileName = paste0("Community", i, ".dat")
    write.table(EL, FileName, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep=",")
}
```